# Complete set of orthonormal functions on $W^{2,2}([0,1]^2, \mathbb{R}^2)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Consider $L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

Then,
$$1, \sqrt{2} \cos(2 \pi j x), \sqrt{2} \sin(2 \pi j x ), \quad j =1,2,\ldots$$

is a Schauder basis on $L^2([0,1], \mathbb{R})$.

I am curious, how does this generalize for the *Sobolev space* $W^{2,2}([0,1]^2, \mathbb{R}^2)$ ?

Comment: The second answer here seems relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261941/orthonormal-basis-in-w1-20-1?rq=1

Comment: See the article:"Développements des distributions en séries de fonctions orthogonales. Séries de Legendre et de Lagurre"  by Marianne Guillemot-Teissier which can  easily be found online.

Comment: Starting from the trigonometric system $e_j(x)$, sure you get a Hilbert basis of $W^{2,2}([0,1]^2)$ of the form $c_{jk}e_j(x)e_k(y)$